# Quick question on complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

For $f(z) = (1-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, how do I show that the integral of $f(z)$ from $0$ to $\pi$ is $O(R^{-2})$?

$$\int f(z) dz = \int \frac{1}{z(1-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} dz   $$

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is unclear: If $z = Re^{i\theta}$, and you're integrating from $z = 0$ to $z = \pi$, $z$ wouldn't be that large. Can you clarify the contour?

Comment: the contour is a semi-circle centered on the origin

Comment: Is it a semi-circle of radius $R$, connected with a line segment? If so, what does this have to do with integrating from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: I have to show that the line integral about $\Gamma_1$ goes to zero as the the radius of the circle goes to $\infty$

Comment: What is the contour? $|z| = 1$? Beware of branch points/cuts. If $|z| < 1$, then the integral is clearly $0$, since the function is holomorphic on the domain. If $|z| = 1$, take the limits at the branch points $z = 1$ and $z=-1$.

Comment: At the moment, I'm trying to show that the line integral along $\Gamma_1$ goes to $0$ as $R\rightarrow \infty$, and if possible to show it is $O(R^{-2})$.

Comment: @user44840, was writing comment when you added update. Things are much clearer now.

Comment: @user44840, are you sure that the integral is $0$? From inspection, it looks as if the integral over $\Gamma_{1}$ is equal to the integral over $\Gamma_{2}$ and that these two cancel out.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I just realized I was looking at the wrong formula for the past 20 minutes! and yes crudely the integrand is of order $\frac{1}{R^2}$.

I have uploaded the full question here, if anyone's interested in pursuing it.

Comment: I don't think it is zero. As written, the integrand is of the order of $R^3$. It must be that it is the opposite of the integral over the lower semicircle ($\pi<\theta<2\pi$), right?

Comment: It appears that by using the function they gave us, the integrand simply turns out to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$, by residue theorem

Comment: Thanks so much for your all your help everyone, I think I got it. I simply read the formula wrong at the start - I've edited it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left | \int_0^\pi f(Re^{i \theta}) d ( R e^{i \theta}) \right | = \left | \int_0^\pi  \frac{ i  d \theta}{  \sqrt{ 1- R^2 e^{2 i \theta}}} \right | \leq \int_0^ \pi \frac{ d \theta}{ \sqrt{1 + R^2} } = \frac{ \pi }{ \sqrt{ 1 + R^2}} \to 0$$

as $R \to \infty$. Notice that it's just $O(R^{-1})$